# Streaming parquet file python and only downsampling

Tags: python-3.x, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have data in parquet format which is too big to fit into memory (6 GB). I am looking for a way to read and process the file using Python 3.6. Is there a way to stream the file, down-sample, and save to a `dataframe`? Ultimately, I would like to have the data in `dataframe` format to work with.

Am I wrong to attempt to do this without using a spark framework?

I have tried using `pyarrow` and `fastparquet` but I get memory errors on trying to read the entire file in. 
Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Spark is certainly a viable choice for this task.

We're planning to add streaming read logic in `pyarrow` this year (2019, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3771 and related issues). In the meantime, I would recommend reading one row group at a time to mitigate the memory use issues. You can do this with `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile` and its `read_row_group` method

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I have queried the file using 'num_row_groups' and my file has only 1 'row_group'. I assume this means I won't have anything to gain by using 'read_row_group'?

Comment: No, you will only gain something from this when you write your Parquet files with multiple row groups. When using `pyarrow` for writing them, you should set the `chunk_size` argument to the number of rows that fit nicely into RAM. But beware that the smaller you set this argument, the slower reading gets. You're probably best of by setting it `chunk_size=len(table) / 60` so that you get 100 MiB chunks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I do not have control of the parquet file format. I assume my only option is to get set-up with pyspark/spark?